# Safari Extension Help! Displaying Context Menu Item Only When user Right Clicks on An Class

Tags: contextmenu, safari-extension

I have a simple question regarding the Context Menu Item for Safari Extensions. I only want the context menu item "Menu Item Label A" to appear when the user right clicks on a particular class on the HTML page. Any ideas what types of events I should be listening to or how I should accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: This should get you going in the right direction. I'm sure it is as simple as checking the class of the clicked item in the callback.  https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingContextualMenuItems/AddingContextualMenuItems.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried listening to the "contextmenu" event, but it doesn't seem to be giving me the HTML element the user is right clicking on, but instead some "SafariBrowserTab" object. And even if I did get it, I'm not sure how to prevent a context menu item from showing up.

Comment: Hmm, leave it to Safari huh? :P Have you tried inspecting the SafariTab object? Check its children, and even its children's children. You may find the clicked object in there. Also, this is a **complete guess**, but maybe returning `false` in the callback will prevent the context menu from displaying?

Comment: I just double checked the docs and it really looks like `event.target` returns the clicked object.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Safari extension and I'm not even sure what's the best way to debug it besides making "alert" calls. "console.log" doesn't seem to be working. I'll look into the "SafariBrowserTab", but I don't think it will give me the HTML element the user right clicked on. I want to prevent a menu item from showing, not really the entire context menu. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @LukeSapan event.target for the event "command" gave me a "SafarContextMenuItem" object. event.target for the event "contextmenu" gave me the "SafariBrowserTab" object. When I called "alert(event.target)"

Answer (score 4):

What you need is an injected script. See the documentation page that Luke linked to, under the heading "Adding Context Information". Your injected script must have a "contextmenu" event handler like this one:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (evt) {
    safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(evt, evt.target.className);
}, false);
```

In your global page script, you should have something like this:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (evt) {
    // evt.userInfo will have the classname of the right-clicked element
    if (evt.userInfo == 'my_special_className') {
        evt.contextMenu.appendContextMenuItem('myCommandName', 'My Context Menu Item');
    } else {
        // don't insert the context menu item
    }
}, false);
```

More about injected scripts: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html

More about setContextMenuEventUserInfo: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions/safaricontentbrowsertabproxy

Comment: Remember that the `target` of the `contextmenu` event may not have the classname you're looking for, but that one of its ancestors might. If this matters, you'll have to check the classnames of all the ancestors of the event target.